# How to do an efficient case insensitive search

Tags: mysql, case

As an example, take a **city** table with 2 columns

- city_ref (bigint)
- city_name (varchar)

with indexes on both.

I want to do a case independent search by city_name.

1. I know I can use **like** but that's not very efficient.
2. One way would be to store the Uppercase variation of the city_name in **another field**.
3. But I can't help but think that there should be a way to use charset or collation to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: AFAIK you CANNOT use like for a case insensitive search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using `LIKE`, as long as it's in a format such as:

`SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE City_Name LIKE 'Abc%';`

This can use an index. However, the following cannot.

`SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE City_Name LIKE UPPER('Abc%');`

The use of a function (`UPPER()`) negates the index - in technical terms, the query is not [`sargable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Note that the query is also non-sargable in a case such as:

`SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE City_Name LIKE  '%Abc..';`

The wild card at the beginning of the search string renders any index non-functional.

An ON INSERT and and ON UPDATE trigger into a new field (up_City_Name) setting the input City_Name to UPPER(input City_Name).

That way, you will always know that your City_Name is in upper case, and your server will always be able to use an index, provided you search on the new field up_City_Name.

Comment: You can't create an index for UPPER(column) in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL [doesn't support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10595073/470530) function based indexes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Would be a lot nicer solution.

Comment: Maybe you could try MariaDB? They do all sorts of interesting things with COMPUTED columns - if that would work for you?

Comment: This does not really add anthing more to what was in my question.  I am still holding out for an example with collation

Comment: As far as I can see, you have the option of TRIGGERs with MySQL or COMPUTED columns with MariaDB. A case insensitive CHARSET doesn't make much sense to me - at least for European languages. Case insensitive COLLATIONs do - but they're about sorting - not searching.